# Effect of alien shrine on Armando

Tags: plot-device, the-familiar

In the short story "The Familiar" by author David Farland (released as part of the short story collection "[Alien Artifacts](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=l47jDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&lpg=PT61&dq=David%20Farland%20%22the%20familiar%22&source=bl&ots=CvnWnM9yIJ&sig=yt3kLEcrt03cb9W8hfZCFf1VZDw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXg8q71PLTAhUlLcAKHYBdAesQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=David%20Farland%20%22the%20familiar%22&f=false)"), protagonist Armando encounters an alien artifact on the surface of Europa.

The artifact has the shape of a huge flower with bronze petals. At its center there is a ghostly humanoid figure. As he approaches a pair of purple eyes appear. Their gaze has Armando feel like something entered his mind/skull.

**Does this have a persisting effect on Armando? What is the meaning of this encounter with regards to the plot?**

Comment: @Valorum - I'd have gone with an author tag per the [specific short story policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10230/51379), but a short story tag is OK.

Comment: @Adamant - I felt that the title was sufficiently unique. Also, it's not like we're likely to have a vast influx of David Farland (who he?) questions burying the tag. I'm also not a huge fan of author tags in the first place.

Comment: @Valorum If you don't know about Farland I recommend you to have a look into his Runelord series.